# Socket odd behaviour

Tags: java, sockets

Playing with Socket encountered odd behaviour.

This is my code:

```
private void processClientRequest(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
        try (
                    final InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                    final OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))
        ) {

//                System.out.println("input: " + reader.readLine());
        out.write(("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n<html>" +
                        "<head><link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/gif\" href=\"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAAAEALAAAAAAQABAAAAIgjI+py+0PEQiT1lkNpppnz4HfdoEH2W1nCJRfBMfyfBQAOw==\" /></head>"+
                        "<body>SingleThreadedServer:" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "</body></html>").getBytes());
        } finally {
            clientSocket.close();
        }

        System.out.println("time spend: " + (System.nanoTime() - start) + " ns");
}
```

I'm using a browser to make requests. If I don't read `inputStream` (comment `reader.readLine()`) and when I make request from browser one time I get this error

> `localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

on next request server response correctly.
`SingleThreadedServer:1486727454378`

and so over request, 
 If I uncomment this line all works perfactly.

```
System.out.println("input: " + reader.readLine());
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Where do you get that error? In browser? If on Server: please add a stacktrace.

Comment: in browser. Browser says that no response on request

Comment: Have you tried flushing before closing the socket? I thought it should flush on close ... but who knows ...

Comment: Yes I have tried same result.

Comment: Try replacing **\n** with **\r\n**. I think CRLF is required not just LF.